# How to fill TableView with ObservableMap<KeyObject, ObservableList<CustomObject>> in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tableview, tablecolumn

My Java program produces a lot of data, with which I construct individual ResultObject. Because only certain ResultsObjects will be of interest, I populate an ObservableHashMap<> with my results. The CustomObject consists of a handful ints + doubles and one JSONObject. With this CustomObject I want to map similar ResultObjects(which have certain properties in common) to that one CustomObject.

While mapping and handling those results works as intended, I am pretty much helpless to populate a TableView with that ObservableHashMap<>.

My CustomObject (JSONObject simply to check, if two CustomObjects have the same properties):

```
public CustomObject(Simulation data) {

    this.datapoint1 = data.datapoint1;
    this.datapoint2 = data.datapoint2;

    this.jsonCompareObject = new JSONObject()
            .put("datapoint1", data.datapoint1)
            .put("datapoint1", data.datapoint2);
}
```

My ObservableHashMap Object:

```
private ObservableMap <CustomObject, ObservableList<Simulation>> topResultsList;

public SomeObjectWithObservableMap(){
    this.topResultsList = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
}
```

By using the following code, I check if there is a key with the corresponding datapoints already present to then add to its ObservableList (Value):

```
private boolean isKeyPresent(CustomObject newCustomObject, Simulation data) {
    for (CustomObject oldCustomObject : this.topResultsList.keySet()) {
        if (oldCustomObject.jsonCompareObject.toString().equals(newCustomObject.jsonCompareObject.toString())) {
            this.topResultsList.get(oldCustomObject).add(data);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I populate some other TableView like this:

```
{
    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("datapoint1"));
    tableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<SomeObject, Double>forTableColumn(twoDigits));
    tableView.setItems(someObject.getObservableList());
}
```

In the end I want some TableColumns to show properties from the CustomObject. Later on, I would want the individual mapped ObservableLists of a selected CustomObject to be shown in a separate TableView.

I am pretty new to Java and JavaFX and I hope to have described my problem as professional as possible. Please let me know, if I missed anything.

Comment: Since you can't back a TableView with a Map, have you tried to use an ObservableList backed by the keySet of the map as your TableView items?  You should be able to listen for changes to the observable map and then either a) whole sale update the TableView items or b) dynamically add/remove just those entries updated in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a `List<Map<String,String>>`

[image]

**Main.java**

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Tester extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        TableView<LineItem> table = new TableView<>();
        List<Map<String, String>> databaseObject = getDatabaseObject();

        for (String key : databaseObject.get(0).keySet())
        {
            TableColumn<LineItem, String> col = new TableColumn<>(key);
            col.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<LineItem, String> cellData) -> cellData.getValue().fieldProperty(key));            
            table.getColumns().add(col);

        }
        List<LineItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        LineItem sequence1 = new LineItem(databaseObject.get(0));
        LineItem sequence2 = new LineItem(databaseObject.get(1));
        data.add(sequence1);
        data.add(sequence2);

        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));

        table.setPrefWidth(500);

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private List<Map<String, String>> getDatabaseObject()
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, String> record1 = new HashMap<>();
        record1.put("firstName", "Joe");
        record1.put("lastName", "Blob");
        record1.put("address", "95 circle ave");
        record1.put("city", "Toronto");
        record1.put("postalCode", "L9Y4Z4");
        values.add(record1);

        Map<String, String> record2 = new HashMap<>();
        record2.put("firstName", "Sarah");
        record2.put("lastName", "Blob");
        record2.put("address", "92 main st");
        record2.put("city", "London");
        record2.put("postalCode", "T9Y4K4");
        values.add(record2);

        return values;
    }

}
```

**LineItem.java**

```
package tester;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class LineItem
{

    private final Map<String, StringProperty> fields;

    public LineItem(Map<String, String> record)
    {
        this.fields = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key : record.keySet())
        {
            this.fields.put(key, new SimpleStringProperty());
        }
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : ((Set<Entry<String, String>>) record.entrySet()))
        {

            this.fields.get(entry.getKey()).set(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public final StringProperty fieldProperty(String key)
    {
        return this.fields.get(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! By studying your code, I realized that I had a too complex structure than needed and restructured my Lists and Maps a little bit with regards to your code. Now it is way more convinient for me to handle those results! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to create a `TableView` with one `Map<String,String>` is:

[image]

**Main.java**

```
package tester;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Tester extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        MapTable mapTable = new MapTable(getDatabaseRecord());

        TableView table = mapTable.getTableView();

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getDatabaseRecord()
    {
        Map<String, String> record1 = new HashMap<>();

        record1.put("firstName", "Joe");
        record1.put("lastName", "Blob");
        record1.put("address", "95 circle ave");
        record1.put("city", "Toronto");
        record1.put("postalCode", "L9Y4Z4");

        return record1;
    }
}
```

**MapTable.java**

```
package tester;

import java.util.Map;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class MapTable
{

    private final TableView<Map.Entry<String, String>> table;
    private final ObservableList<Map.Entry<String, String>> data;

    public MapTable(Map map)
    {

        this.table = new TableView<>();
        this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet());
        setUpTable();
    }

    private void setUpTable()
    {
        this.table.setEditable(false);
        this.table.setItems(this.data);
        this.table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        // use fully detailed type for Map.Entry<String, String> 
        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> column1 = new TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>();
        column1.setMinWidth(125);
        column1.setSortable(false);
        column1.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey()));

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> column2 = new TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>();
        column2.setMinWidth(350);
        column2.setSortable(false);
        column2.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getValue()));


        this.table.getColumns().setAll(column1, column2);

    }

    public TableView getTableView()
    {
        return this.table;
    }
}
```