# javaFX tableView with Map

Tags: javafx

How to write data in table?
I have `class Database` which contains field`Long id` in database I have `Map<Long, Product>` where I want to store my products.
I also have `class Product` which contains fields `String name; BigDecimal price; Category category;//category is Enum`.
And in `class Controller`:

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<Map> tableWithProductsId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Map, Long> productIdColumn;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("0.50");
        BigDecimal price1 = new BigDecimal("5.25");
        BigDecimal price2 = new BigDecimal("0.79");
        Product product = new Product("Apple", price, Category.FRUIT);
        Product product1 = new Product("Mango", price2, Category.FRUIT);
        Product product2 = new Product("Potatoe", price1, Category.VEGETABLE);

        Database database = new Database();
        database.saveProduct(product);
        database.saveProduct(product1);
        database.saveProduct(product2);

        Map<Long, Product> allProductsFromDatabase = database.getAllProducts();
        ObservableList<Map> listOfProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allProductsFromDatabase);

        tableWithProductsId.setItems(listOfProducts);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory<>("name"));//this not works
        //how to setCellValueFactory
```

I tried this link also:[docs.oracle.MapValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/MapValueFactory.html) but this won't work for me.

I want to achieve something like this: [image]
Where `productId` I can get from `class Database;` with method  `getProductId();` and other fields I can get from `class Product;` with methods `getProductName();...` maybe I need to change my `tableView` field on `@FXML private TableView<Map<Long, Product>> tableWithProductsId;`
? and table columns also need to be changed on `@FXML private TableColumn<Map<Long, Product>, String> nameColumn;`? I don't understand how to do this correctly.

Comment: All the items seem to be stored in a single map. You either need to use the keys in the map (or `Map.Entry`s) as items in case you need access to the keys or simply use the values as items (`ObservableList<Map> listOfProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allProductsFromDatabase.values());`). The former approach would require you to write custom cellValueFactorys: `cd -> new SimpleLongProperty(cd.getValue())` and `cd -> allProductsFromDatabase.get(cd.getValue()).nameProperty()` and the like respecively when using the keys as item type.

Comment: what is method `.nameProperty()`. this line shows mistake `ObservableList<Map> listOfProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allProductsFromDatabase.values());`. If I'm right this is more suitable for me `ObservableList<Map<Long, Product>> listOfProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allProductsFromDatabase);
`.? But how to rewrite `cellValueFactory(/*???*/)`?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and have a look if this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55795528/203657) might help you

Comment: @IljaTarasovs That would be a method that could be part of your `Product` class (as discribed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) You may instead wrap the value you retrieve via getter in a property object instead...