# Showing the values of an ArrayList<List<String>> in a TableView (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, arraylist, tableview

I' m trying to create a TableView from a dataset consisting of a doublenested ArrayList with String values. Unfortunately, I cannot display all values in a TableView. The rows are not numbered according to the data set.

The most solutions of the internet demonstrate, that I should use a specific object instance. However, I do not work that way. Instead, I use a matrix of Strings that has an indefinite size. The data is structured as follows:

```
List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

int rows = 10;
int cols = 4;
             
for(int r=0; r<rows; r++) {
    List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
                     
        for(int c=0; c<cols; c++)
            line.add("r: "+r+", c: "+c);
                     
    values.add(line);
}
```

My best (but wrong) result was achieved with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // create values
        List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        int rows = 10;
        int cols = 4;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                line.add("r: " + r + ", c: " + c);

            values.add(line);
        }

        // show values in table
        TableView<List<StringProperty>> tableView = new TableView<List<StringProperty>>();
        ObservableList<List<StringProperty>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            TableColumn<List<StringProperty>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Col: " + c);
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < values.size(); r++) {
            List<StringProperty> row = new ArrayList<StringProperty>();

            for (int c = 0; c < values.get(r).size(); c++) {
                TableColumn<List<StringProperty>, String> col = (TableColumn<List<StringProperty>, String>) tableView.getColumns().get(c);
                String val = values.get(r).get(c);

                col.setCellValueFactory(cl -> new SimpleStringProperty(new String(val)));
            }

            data.add(row);
        }

        tableView.setItems(data);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 300, 500));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

It gives the following result:

[image]

However, the table does not show the numbered rows. I have already tried many things. But I did not get a satisfactory result. What is my mistake?

Comment: You change the factory every time you add a new row. So at the end, you just have a cell factory that produces the data from the last row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill TableView with ObservableMap<KeyObject, ObservableList<CustomObject>> in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795528/how-to-fill-tableview-with-observablemapkeyobject-observablelistcustomobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cellValueFactory` for a given column is a function that takes a wrapper containing the data for a row (i.e. the `List<StringProperty>`) and generates the `ObservableValue` (e.g. a `Property`) whose value is to be displayed in that row and column.

In your code you change the `cellValueFactory` every time you add a row, so the resulting `cellValueFactory` is just the one from the last row you add, and you see only the data from the last row.

You should set the `cellValueFactory` just once per column, and it should be a function mapping the row data to the specific value for that column.

For example, the following will give you what you need:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // create values
    List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 4;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            line.add("r: " + r + ", c: " + c);

        values.add(line);
    }

    // show values in table
    TableView<List<StringProperty>> tableView = new TableView<>();
    ObservableList<List<StringProperty>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        TableColumn<List<StringProperty>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Col: " + c);
        
        final int colIndex = c ;
        col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().get(colIndex));
        
        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < values.size(); r++) {
        List<StringProperty> row = new ArrayList<StringProperty>();

        for (int c = 0; c < values.get(r).size(); c++) {
            row.add(new SimpleStringProperty(values.get(r).get(c)));
        }

        data.add(row);
    }

    tableView.setItems(data);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 300, 500));
    stage.show();
}
```

If the data are not going to change, you might prefer to use something lighter weight than a `StringProperty`, though the benefit to this small performance saving is debatable:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // create values
    List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 4;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            line.add("r: " + r + ", c: " + c);

        values.add(line);
    }

    // show values in table
    TableView<List<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();

    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        TableColumn<List<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Col: " + c);
        
        final int colIndex = c ;
        col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new ObservableValue<String>() {

            // If data are immutable, there's nothing for a listener to do, so we ignore them:
            @Override
            public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {}
            @Override
            public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {}
            @Override
            public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {}
            @Override
            public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {}

            @Override
            public String getValue() {
                return cd.getValue().get(colIndex);
            }
            
        });
        
        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
    }

    

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(values));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 300, 500));
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how it seems to work...i have been guided by
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // create values
    List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 4;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            line.add("r: " + r + ", c: " + c);

        values.add(line);
    }

    
    List<String> colHeads = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        String ch = "Col: " + c; 
        colHeads.add(ch);
    }
    
    
    // show values in table 
    List<TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>> tcs = new ArrayList<TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>>();
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        String ch =  colHeads.get(c);
        
        TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(ch);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(ch)); 
        
        tcs.add(col); 
    }
    
    TableView<Map<String, String>> tableView = new TableView<>(generateDataInMap(colHeads, values));
    tableView.getColumns().setAll(tcs);
     

    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 300, 500));
    stage.show();

}

private ObservableList<Map<String, String>> generateDataInMap(List<String> colHeads, List<List<String>> values ) {

    ObservableList<Map<String, String>> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    for(int r=0; r<values.size(); r++) {
        Map<String, String> dataRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        for(int c=0; c<values.get(r).size(); c++) {
            String val = values.get(r).get(c);
            dataRow.put(colHeads.get(c), val);
        }
        allData.add(dataRow);
    }
    return allData;
}
```

Comment: Your "guide" is for pre Java 8. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm) is the Java 8 version.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `final int colIndex = c ;` and `col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().get(colIndex)));`?