# JavaFX - create vertical Table

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want to use a "vertical" table for my JavaFX project. So that's how a normal table in JavaFX looks like:

[image]

And that's how I want my table should look like:

[image]

Is there any function for that in JavaFX, if not does sb got a nice idea for a great workaround?

LG
bttl

Comment: Is it required to be editable?  If so, you could use a controlsfx [PropertySheet](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/jfx-13/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.java), which [looks like this](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/jfx-13/controlsfx/src/main/docs/org/controlsfx/control/propertySheet.PNG?raw=true).

Comment: You could probably also disable editing on the PropertySheet to make it read-only if you wished, though there may be easier ways to achieve what you want without a PropertySheet if it is read-only (e.g. use a GridPane layout and define all the fields in it using FXML).

Comment: Its just to show a result, so I don't need a editable table

Comment: Use this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55803724/9278333

Comment: How much data are there? Do you need selection? It might be easier just to use a `GridPane`.